# R - retrieve row numbers after sorting

Tags: r, sorting

I was wondering how I could retrieve the row numbers after having sorted my data.

Let us imagine my vector is this one:

```
vec = c("GET FRESH", "EASTENDERS", "WORLD CUP", "SPORT", "DYNASTY" )
```

and then I sort

```
sort(vec)
[1] "DYNASTY"    "EASTENDERS" "GET FRESH"  "SPORT"      "WORLD CUP"
```

How could I get the row numbers of each case?

```
     vec          rownumber
[1,] "DYNASTY"    "5"      
[2,] "EASTENDERS" "2"      
[3,] "GET FRESH"  "1"      
[4,] "SPORT"      "4"      
[5,] "WORLD CUP"  "3"
```

Comment: Also maybe `match(sort(vec), vec)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg In cases of ties, this may result in same index.

Comment: @akrun probably. Your solution is better.

Comment: Also `data.frame(vec = vec[o <- order(vec)], rownumber = o)` would do it

Comment: Eastenders is my parents' favorite show.

Comment: @RichardScriven - I am doing some data cleaning of 1980's British shows so I am discovering lots of new tv program and movies !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with `index.return=TRUE`.  It returns a `list` of sorted values and the index, which can be converted to 'data.frame'

```
data.frame(sort(vec, index.return=TRUE))
#           x ix
#1    DYNASTY  5
#2 EASTENDERS  2
#3  GET FRESH  1
#4      SPORT  4
#5  WORLD CUP  3
```